# Dirichlet's Approximation Theorem For Rationals

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Dirichlet's Approximation Theorem implies that for all $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ we have
$$
\left|x-\frac{p}{q} \right| \leq \frac{1}{|q|^2} \quad \text{for infinitely many $(p,q) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$.}
$$
This fails for $x \in \mathbb{Q}$:
$$
\left|\frac{a}{b}-\frac{p}{q} \right| = \left|\frac{aq - bp}{bq}\right| \geq \frac{1}{|b||q|} \quad \text{if } \frac{a}{b} \neq \frac{p}{q}.
$$

Is there an $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ we have
$$
\left|x-\frac{p}{q} \right| \leq \frac{1}{|q|^{1+\epsilon}} \quad \text{for infinitely many $(p,q) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$?}
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x = \dfrac{a}{b}\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $x \neq \dfrac{p}{q}$, we have, as you wrote yourself in the question,

$$\frac{1}{\lvert b\rvert\cdot \lvert q\rvert} \leqslant \left\lvert x - \frac{p}{q}\right\rvert,$$

so an inequality

$$\left\lvert x - \frac{p}{q}\right\rvert \leqslant \frac{1}{\lvert q\rvert^{1+\varepsilon}}\tag{1}$$

can only hold if $$\lvert q\rvert^\varepsilon \leqslant \lvert b\rvert \iff \lvert q\rvert \leqslant \lvert b\rvert^{1/\varepsilon}.$$

So whatever positive $\varepsilon$ one chooses, $(1)$ can only hold for finitely many $q$. And for each of these $q$, only for finitely many $p$.